# what is wrong with toDateString

Tags: javascript, cookies

Following is a script+HTML that tells the user his last visit to page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cookie</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = initLastVisit;

function initLastVisit() {
var now = new Date();
var last = new Date();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth()+6);
document.cookie = "lastVisit=" + last.toDateString() + ";path=/;expires=" + now.toGMTString();
document.getElementById("lastVisitedOn").innerHTML = document.cookie.split("=")[1];
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<label>Enter your name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name_field" /></label> <br/>
</form>
<h1 id="lastVisitedOn"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The statement that sets the cookie in the above script is : `document.cookie = "lastVisit=" + last.toDateString() + ";path=/;expires=" + now.toGMTString();` . If in this i replace `now.toGMTString()` with `now.toDateString()` the expire time in the browser is **"Expires when i close my browser"** . Why is that ?
It is ok with `toGMTString` . The expire date is in march 2012 as expected.

Comment: Why do you want to use "toDateString()" instead of "toGMTString()"?  Or are you just curious as to why things are the way they are?

Comment: .toDateStr tends output in different formats than .toGMTString. Most likely whatever your browser is outputting can't be interepreted as a proper date for cookie usage, so it's just going with interpreting it as a 0, which is expires-on-close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try them both in the console, you will see that they don't give the same resulting string at all:

```
(new Date()).toGMTString();
"Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:33:01 GMT"

(new Date()).toDateString();
"Fri Sep 23 2011"
```

When you set a cookie [you have to specify the time using GMT format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age), if you don't your browser fail to recognize the expiry time and consider that none was specified. [When no expiry date is specified, cookie are created as "session cookie"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie), which expires once the session end (eg you close your browser).

So when you use toDateString(), it is an invalid expiry format, your browser discards it and use its default value of creating a session cookie.

Comment: acc to [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529307/unable-to-display-the-last-visited-date/7529840#7529840) _toGMTString is deprecated_ . If it is so , what is the replacement ?

Comment: [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) is meant to replace it. It is basically the same thing, only better. As [the UTC wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) states; "UTC is conceptually different from Universal Time and Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), but it can be used interchangeably where sub-second precision is not required.", since expiry time for cookies is second based, sub second precision is obviously not required.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the format that is output from `toDateString()` which is not valid for specifying the expiry date for a cookie.
* `toDateString()` - `Fri Sep 23 2011`
* `toGMTString()` - `Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:31:24 GMT`

Due to the date string not being recognised the cookie will use default behaviour and expire at the end of the session.

Answer (score 0):

toDateString does not produce a valid date- there is no time zone, and no time data included.
toGMT string returns an **unambiguous** time.

I always wished for an integer time stamp, but a javascript timestamp is milliseconds-a thousand times bigger  than the 'unix' seconds format.

There is always **max-age**.